# How do I cover exposed exposed wood under cracked stucco?

Tags: moisture, crack, stucco, patch, cover

Let me set up some context:
My house is at the bottom of a hill, so when it rains, the water flows down North, into my back yard, and pools on the  North and South-facing sides of my house.
Over time this has caused structural damage. The south-facing side had its foundational wall replaced entirely, so the stucco siding on it is in satisfactory condition, but still has cracked. The north-facing side has a failing foundation. So, this causes the house to rotate northward vertically. As a result, the stucco siding has a crack running parallel to the top of the basement windows, and it has also moved away from them. Pictured below are the different gaps between the siding and each window. I'm looking for a temporary solution to prevent water, rodents, and insects from getting into these cracks while I shore up the foundation and add drainage on the Southside (those are subjects that could be their own posts though).

Please let me know what you think

[image: Crack over window 1]

[image: Crack over window 2]
[image: Exposed wood over window 3]

Comment: Is there a way you could post additional pictures (or replace existing ones) that show some scale of the damage, like maybe some taken from farther back?

Comment: Sorry, If I had seen this earlier, I would have done as you recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary?  Spray foam.

For rodent proof stuff rat wire in the hole, then spray foam.

Answer (score 1):

Some pre-caulking gap filler rope and possibly some Bondo[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I put hydraulic cement over the cracks. Wish I hadn't since both of you gave better solutions, I just forgot to check the dang website and we had a storm coming today so I wanted just used what I had around the house. Didn't wanna leave you hanging. Next time around, I would look into your ideas.

Comment: Drastic measures sometimes require drastic measures. Get what you need to fix this right for when weather permits you to apply a permanent fix.